# grub overwrites windows boot manager after every update

Tags: windows, wubi, grub2

error: no such device: (hard drive serial number).
grub rescue>

Thats what i get after every update, I know how to recover from this error. But i Don't want it to recur. What should I do?

Comment: Based on the tags, I assume you are using Wubi?  It would be useful to add that info to your question.  Also: how do you recover from it?

Comment: Do you still have the problem. Have you found how to solved the problem or considered accepting an answer that solves your problem (if any)?

Answer (score 1):

I would try editing **/etc/grub.d/40_custom** and on the bottom add your Windows menuentry that looks like this `menuentry "Windows" { ... }`